# How can I see what's in the Docker layers?

Tags: docker

I am running a docker build and one of the layers is big and always takes a long time to download.  Is there a way to see where the layer is coming from and what it does?  I would like to check it while it's downloading but it would still be useful to examine it after download.  Is either possible?

This is the command, I am running:

```
docker build \
        -t registry.gear.ge.com/predix_edge/edge-agent-i386 \
        -f docker-runners/.dockerfile-build-i386 docker-runners
Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.027MB
Step 1/13 : FROM registry.gear.ge.com/predix_edge/edge-agent-build-i386:20180920
20180920: Pulling from predix_edge/edge-agent-build-i386
10c05d2b2fbf: Pull complete 
3f9f2d6d7ae5: Pull complete 
a2f288eed9a5: Pull complete 
8fadaaf1d0d3: Pull complete 
5c746e81cede: Pull complete 
20d91e41d92e: Downloading [===============>                                   ]  113.4MB/366.3MB
c0701269de1c: Download complete 
e6a6642f6692: Download complete 
ccac838d533e: Download complete 
0e3809b7d911: Download complete 
e0b7e3addbed: Verifying Checksum
```

I would like to see what's in layer `20d91e41d92e`.

Answer (score 0):

`docker history` will give you a listing of all of the layers in an image, the individual layer’s size, and the command that got run to create the image.  That could be a shell command or a Dockerfile directive.

In practice, a very large layer will probably be either COPYing some artifact into Docker land, or a software installation of some sort.  Depending on what it is that’s being installed, working around this may or may not be tricky.  I see a lot of Dockerfiles go by on SO that install a full C toolchain and library header files just to produce a runnable Python library, for instance; that can be split into a multi-stage build that will have a much smaller runtime artifact, but that involves reengineering the build process.

Comment: I'm not seeing layer `20d91e41d92e` in `docker history` and I didn't last time I tried that.  Are you sure that the layers listed in `docker build` are the same as those listed in `docker history`?

Comment: Trying it locally, I see the same image IDs in both (though in reverse order: in `docker history` the newest layer is first).  `docker history` also includes the size of each layer so even if the IDs don’t match up, look for the really big layer.